# Streamlabs Custom CSS Event List - Adding a delay for new entries

Tags: css, twitch, alerts

I want to add a delay to my **Streamlabs Event List**, so that it won't spoil my regular Twitch Alerts. Right now, it will display new alerts immediately as they happen. There is no option for it on the website, so I guess I can only do that with **Custom CSS**.

I basically just want the event list to wait for 30 seconds when I get a new follower, subscriber etc. before it starts showing it on the list.

Here is the CSS File that I'm using. It works perfectly fine, I just have no idea how to delay it.

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=$font_family");

html, .widget-EventList li > div {
transform: rotateX($rotate_x) rotateY($rotate_y);
}

.widget-EventList {
font-weight: 400;
font-size: $font_size;
font-family: "$font_family";
overflow: hidden;
color: #444;
list-style: none;
padding: 0;
text-transform: uppercase;
position: relative;
background: transparente;
transform: rotate(180deg);
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 10px;
}

.widget-EventList, .widget-EventList * {
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.widget-EventList li {
transform: rotate(-180deg);
line-height: 1.3em;
overflow: hidden;
margin-bottom: 0.1em;
}

.widget-EventList li > div:last-child {
/*padding: 0 10px;*/
height: 1.3em;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
z-index: 10;
text-align: right;
display: inline-block;
float: right;
white-space: nowrap;
}

.widget-EventList .tag {
float: right;
margin: 0 0.25em;
display: inline-block;
}

.widget-EventList .message {
float: right;
white-space: nowrap;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
margin: 0 0.25em;
display: inline-block;
}

.widget-EventList li:first-child div:last-child {
background: #DCB154;
color: $text_color;
}

.widget-EventList li:nth-child(2) div:last-child {
color: #EEE;
}

.widget-EventList li:nth-child(3) div:last-child {
color: #AAA;
}

.widget-EventList li > div:last-child {
animation: grow 0.5s forwards;
-webkit-animation: grow 0.5s forwards;
}

.widget-EventList li:nth-child(n+ $max_events ) {
animation: fadeOut 1.5s forwards;
-webkit-animation: fadeOut 1.5s forwards;
}

@keyframes grow {
0% {
height: 0;
padding-top: 0;
padding-bottom: 0;
}
}

@-webkit-keyframes grow {
0% {
height: 0;
padding-top: 0;
padding-bottom: 0;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate this is a pretty old topic, but it's unanswered with 3,000 views so...

You want to add in a time-delay on the JavaScript side, not the CSS side.
Change this:

```
document.addEventListener('onEventReceived', function(obj) {
  var listItems = document.querySelectorAll(".listItem");
  var listItemNew = listItems[0];
  SetListItem(listItemNew);
});
```

To something like this (The time parameter here is in miliseconds, and follows the setTimeout function):

```
document.addEventListener('onEventReceived', function(obj) {
  setTimeout(function(){
    var listItems = document.querySelectorAll(".listItem");
    var listItemNew = listItems[0];
    SetListItem(listItemNew);
    
  }, 10000);
});
```